# Executing sql command in powershell script

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell

I want to execute simple sql commands that I do on command by directly entering, but I want to do that using Powershell script, don't want to do the commands using powershell API but by just invoking command

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -U SA -P mypass
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [easypay] FROM  DISK = N'C:\backup.trn' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5
ALTER LOGIN [itdb] WITH PASSWORD=N'abc'
GO
USE [easypay]
GO
EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', 'itdb'
Go
USE [easypay]
GO
sp_changedbowner 'sa'
GO

UPDATE itdb.passwd set password = '1a1dc91c907325c69271ddf0c944bc72'  WHERE itdb.passwd.name = 'abc'
GO
```

I want a powershell script that can execute these commands direclty
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script which I use, little bit modified.
Note this code is untested:

Made some changes after the comment from Kirill Pashkov

```
$SQLServer = "" #your value
$SQLDBName = "" #your value

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
#Start SQL connection
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

#Create querys
#Query 1
$SqlQuery = "Command;"

#Query 2
$SqlQuery2 = @"
 Command
"@

#Add querys to array
$querys = $SqlQuery, $SqlQuery2

# Run Query
Foreach($query in $querys)
{
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $query
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $OutPut = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    if($OutPut -ne 0){
    Write-Host $OutPut
    }

}
#Close SQL connection
$SqlConnection.Close()
```

Comment: This code will not work because 'GO' is an utility command to separate batches(such as sqlcmd or SSMS and etc). You would want to split commands in several query statements.